Conditional Formatting with 3 different conditions
I've inherited an Excel file and need to add some conditional formatting; which I never used, so this is all kind of new to me.  This needs to be kind of dynamic since different users will have different number of rows on their spreadsheet.
There are 24 columns on Sheet1.  The conditional formatting should apply to columns 13 - 24.
The conditional formatting should also apply from row 2 to row 200.
If column 1 is blank, columns 13 - 24 should have a white fill color
If column 1 is not blank, cells in column 13 - 24, should have a white fill color if there is an amount in any of these columns.
If column 1 is not blank, cells in column 13 - 24, should have a green fill color if these columns are blank.
I've tried to add rules using a formula but have not had any success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

'White Fill', 'No Fill'? any reason for not just leaving those without fill (do they have a different colour already)


Jump in to R1C1 mode in Excel.
Select the cells that you want to have the conditional formatting.
Add the rule =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(RC1)),ISBLANK(RC))
Set the fill to Green
Optionally revert back to the awful A1 mode.



@enigmativity............Thank you.  Works like a charm.  Does exactly what I want it to.  Thanks again....

Select the area you want conditional formatting to apply, and:

Choose Conditional Formatting (drop down)->Manage Rules
New Rule->Use a formula to determine which cells to format
In Format values where this formula is true: type  =ISBLANK($A2)
Click Format, and choose Fill -> choose the white colour you want.
Ok->Ok
New Rule->Format only cells that contain
In the Format only cells with: choose Blanks
Click Format, and choose Fill -> choose the green colour you want.
Click Ok
Make sure that the rules appear in this order (I yellow instead of white to make it obvious for myself); if not, you can use the arrow buttons above to move them up/down.
Ok



@tinazmu........Thanks for the suggestion
